# nginx 504 Gateway Time-out since 60 seconds time

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm getting a `504 Gateway Time-out` error:

[image]

when I call a service which is under a proxy reverse of nginx, like this:

```
location ~ ^/myapp/some-service {
  rewrite ^/myapp/some-service(.*)$ $1 break;
  proxy_pass http://my-web.cl-myapp:80;
  proxy_redirect off;
  # proxy_pass http://my-web.cl-myapp:80/;
}
```

The original URL of the service is (example values):

https://my-web.myhosting.com/test?time=61

This one has no timeout error, and I could test it with `?time=300` and will always return 200.

But, if I access the same service through the proxy reverse:

https://subdomain.anotherhosting.cl/myapp/some-service/test?time=61

I get the timeout error.

In the URL there's a parameter to control the timeout (?time), the service is just a NodeJS function that returns 200 after setTimeout with `time` is completed. I made it for replicate at which time the timeout begins, and it is exactly and always at 60 seconds or more.

In some cases I get this error instead:
[image]

But 19 of 20 test I get the first `Gateway timeout` error pointed above.

I don't see any part of my nginx configuration that has an explicit 60 or 60000 seconds/miliseconds for timeouts, idle, or something like that.

Any clue where should I look?

Comment: Hi @pmiranda Did you get a fix for this issue?

Comment: @Mukesh no, we have to deal with it, and our process should not last more than 60 seconds... We were asking to Torbit, CDN, etc, no one were capable to tell us why/where is there that 60 seconds timeout